# PHP wont delete users crontab

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP script that when i press delete all button it will delete all the specific users cron.
I am trying to make it delete all the roots cron jobs but it wont work. Any idea?
I have access to the whole system including roots. I have http user and root.

PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['saveadconfig']))
{
    shell_exec("sudo crontab -r -u root");
}
```

I tried without sudo but i added sudo and still nothing. There is loads more code but i made it simple to read. Thanks!

P.S: It goes into the if statement perfectly its just it wont run the command to remove root crons properly.

I also have

```
http ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

in my /etc/sudoers file. http is the php user.

Comment: anything in logs?

Comment: You cannot provide the root password in such a non interactive manner.

Comment: Where do i look in the logs? What log file? Location? As for @arkascha what do you mean? thanks!

Comment: What I mean? What is there in my comment you cannot understand?

Comment: You're just ASSUMING the exec call suceeded. Never assume success when dealing with external resources. Always assume failure, CHECK for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise: `$output = exec('sudo ...', $output, $exit_value);`

Comment: it's your system, we don't know where your logs are located. Usually `/logs` under root or use error reporting. check permissions also.

Comment: Even with that sudoers setup you _still_ need to provide a password.

Comment: Apart from that: this is an _insane_ security gap.

Comment: I need to provide a password to use sudo? Well then, discarding the sudo part. How do i make it work without the sudo? Thanks.

Comment: If i was to make a new user, and make it all work with php, what would the steps be? I dont know much with permission setting and all sorts. @arkascha

Comment: You cannot do that in a direct manner, since that violates all security ideas on a multi user system. This would mean you can simply go and change other users stuff! That is especially true for the super user root! That is why you have to specify a password to authorize your action. Think about it... What you _can_ do is configure a single command that can be used _without_ having to specify a password (`NOPASSWD`). The sudo man pages documents that (`man sudo`, `man sudoers`). That allows to execute _a specific command_ without the need to authorize using a password in an interactive manner.

Comment: @arkascha I changed my sudoers from the above to: http ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL but still not working. If you can add an answer with detailed step to step instructions that would be a huge help!

Comment: That certainly is _not_ what you should do. It means anyone can use your http server to do whatever he/she wants on your system.

Comment: Apart from that: are you sure that your http server processes are execute under a user account named "http"? That is a _very_ uncommon name...

Comment: Hi @arkascha , yes. If i do: `shell_exec("crontab -r");` and view the users crontab then all the crons are removed. So it works perfectly as http is the main account for the server so all cron events such as 'crontab command' appears under the account http. I just want my php script to be able to access the roots crontab so i can schedule events!:)

Comment: Why do you need roots crontab to "schedule events"? Won't another crontab do? Though I agree that this is not the issue here.

Comment: Sorry, no idea then. Looks fine to me.

Comment: I suggest you finally add error detection and handling just as MarcB already suggested above.

Comment: I created a new user. How do i give http full access over my new user? So i can access the new users crontab. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue was me not providing the full paths to the commands while using sudo!
Another issue was i need to provide a password so i bypassed that with:

NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/crontab in sudoers file.

End result with PHP:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/crontab command
```